# wpf datagrid : row details element positioning

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I would like to align elements inside a row details template, with a column position.

user can move columns so this value would be changing during runtime.

Is it possible to pass a columns position properties to Row Details elements so that they can position accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use shared size scopes feature of Grid control
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: hmm.. thanks, that is something.. 
although my grid in details has different columns with different fields. also i care about position more than the size..

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try following bindings

Left="{Binding Path=Columns[2].Left, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}